# How to install the Tevii S662 driver?

Tags: drivers, 13.10, software-installation

I've downloaded the `Tevii_Product_20140130_media_build_b51.tar.bz2.rar` driver tarball to `~` from the homepage, installed the prerequisites (`git libproc-processtable-perl patchutils make gcc`) on a fresh installed 13.10 `tar xfv` the `.bz2` file, went into the directory, and gave `./build` command.

[Everything went fine.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7165463)

Still after reboot [i see Jactek](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7165469) instead of TeVii S662.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this site: [CrazyCat](https://bitbucket.org/CrazyCat/s2-liplianin-v39)

I also had no success with the package provided by tevii. But I found a solution with the package provided by CrazyCat. It works for me with kernel 3.8...

dmesg output:

```
    [ 4193.268177] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 4193.400993] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=9022, idProduct=d662

[ 4193.401006] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3

[ 4193.401014] usb 1-1: Product: DVB-S/S2 Box

[ 4193.401023] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Jactek

[ 4193.401033] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 000000031

[ 4194.326470] WARNING: You are using an experimental version of the media stack.

[ 4194.326470]  As the driver is backported to an older kernel, it doesn't offer

[ 4194.326470]  enough quality for its usage in production.

[ 4194.326470]  Use it with care.

[ 4194.326470] Latest git patches (needed if you report a bug to linux-media@vger.kernel.org):

[ 4194.326470]  6bf7861fa2bb4be3cc70a6e9aed664ce65270027 [media] si476x: Fix some config dependencies and a compile warnings

[ 4194.326470]  b0efc3ed0530b08e9e1cba5f63e9c251ca3d7428 [media] m920x: Fix uninitialized variable warning

[ 4194.326470]  46f85978687152c53a69fc06951e386f194e7f5d [media] em28xx: fix typo in scale_to_size()

[ 4194.354683] WARNING: You are using an experimental version of the media stack.

[ 4194.354683]  As the driver is backported to an older kernel, it doesn't offer

[ 4194.354683]  enough quality for its usage in production.

[ 4194.354683]  Use it with care.

[ 4194.354683] Latest git patches (needed if you report a bug to linux-media@vger.kernel.org):

[ 4194.354683]  6bf7861fa2bb4be3cc70a6e9aed664ce65270027 [media] si476x: Fix some config dependencies and a compile warnings

[ 4194.354683]  b0efc3ed0530b08e9e1cba5f63e9c251ca3d7428 [media] m920x: Fix uninitialized variable warning

[ 4194.354683]  46f85978687152c53a69fc06951e386f194e7f5d [media] em28xx: fix typo in scale_to_size()

[ 4194.393630] dw2102: su3000_identify_state

[ 4194.393630] 

[ 4194.393644] dvb-usb: found a 'TeVii S662' in warm state.

[ 4194.393669] dw2102: su3000_power_ctrl: 1, initialized 0

[ 4194.393669] 

[ 4194.397082] dvb-usb: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer.

[ 4194.404158] DVB: registering new adapter (TeVii S662)

[ 4194.408725] 00 18 bd 5b 14 bb 

[ 4194.408748] dvb-usb: MAC address: 00:18:bd:5b:14:bb

[ 4195.099311]  Chip ID != [DS300X]! Not supported by this module

[ 4195.107418]  Chip ID = [DS3103]!

[ 4195.107427] DS3103 chip version: 0.208 attached.

[ 4195.133442] dw2102: Attached DS3103/TS2022!

[ 4195.133442] 

[ 4195.133475] usb 1-1: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Montage Technology DS3103/TS2022)...

[ 4195.134167] input: IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-1/input/input11

[ 4195.136878] dvb-usb: schedule remote query interval to 250 msecs.

[ 4195.136897] dw2102: su3000_power_ctrl: 0, initialized 1

[ 4195.136897] 

[ 4195.136907] dvb-usb: TeVii S662 successfully initialized and connected.

[ 4195.136997] usbcore: registered new interface driver dw2102
```